# Sharing PHPStorm file watchers across platforms

Tags: npm, phpstorm, gulp

I want to create a file watcher that runs the (npm) `gulp` command when a file has changed. However, the issue is that I want to be able to commit this watcher to my repo, and have it work on both mac and windows.

The only way I have been able to make this work, is by using the explicit paths of `%appdata%\roaming\npm\gulp.cmd` and `/usr/local/share/npm/bin/gulp`. This would require 2 file watchers, with one being disabled on each platform.

Surely there must be a simpler way of executing a npm tool across the 2 platforms? E.g. for grunt, gulp etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some additional modifications/steps it *should* work (#2 may sound rather stupid, but that's how Windows works).

**1)** You will need to use [`Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Path variables`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/path-variables-2.html) and create the same named variable on all computers where this project will be used (it's IDE-wide settings so it's not stored as part of the project). Variable should point to a folder where `gulp` is located.

For example: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-22610#comment=27-703614

**2)** On platforms other than Windows, you will have to create a symbolic link for `gulp` file -- it should be named `gulp.cmd`. This is needed as Windows recognizes executable file by it's extension so you have to point File Watcher to EXACT file name (in other words, just `gulp` on Windows will NOT work).

The above *should* do the job (sorry, Windows user here -- I do not have access to Mac or Linux to test it).

Related ticket: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11534